# iOS Keyboard Accessory View: barbuttonitem touch events not working normally

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have an input accessory view attached to a keyboard.  The accessory view itself is a UIToolbar, which includes four interactive UIBarButtonItems, a noninteractive UIBarButtonItem which just consists of a UILabel, and some fixed and flexible spaces.  Specifically, the array of items is:

```
@[prevButton,
  nextButton, 
  flexSpace, 
  labelItem, 
  flexSpace, 
  cameraButton, 
  fixedSpace, 
  moreButton]
```

Everything works as you'd expect... except for nextButton.  The prevButton and nextButton items are both initialized as follows:

```
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
  initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"rightArrow.png"]
  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
  target:self
  action:@selector(activateNextField)];
```

(only difference with prevButton is that it uses a different .png and calls a different selector)

But when the accessory view comes up, the nextButton item acts strangely.  It receives taps on its left and right edges, but if you tap it dead-center, it doesn't fire its selector.

The problem occurs in iOS 7 only.

Is there some way to figure out what object *is* receiving that tap?  Or is this an issue someone else has come across?  It's got me stumped.

**UPDATE**:
So -- I haven't figured out the underlying problem, but I did at least find a (weird) workaround...

When the system is iOS 7, I do the following:

```
nextButton.width = 30.0;
nextButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-20,0,0);
```

...and it magically seems to work fine.

Would still very much like to figure out WHY this is going on, though.  This solution feels quite hackish.

Comment: There is a good library handling exactly what you want btw. (https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls). Concerning your problem – is your button getting highlighted on tab? If yes, are you sure that your activateNextField method has no parameters? Missing ':' for the sender attribute in your selector reference is a common error in case your method implementation contains a parameter...

Comment: Well, what's weird is that the button is working fine as long as you tap it somewhere other than right in its center.  If I tap along the right of left edge of the button, it fires its selector and everything works fine.

Comment: Also, thx for the library link, that may well come in handy

Comment: Maybe there is an overlapping view? Further check size of the button

Comment: Nope, no overlapping views, and the button size is the same for both prev and next.

Comment: What happens if, only for testing, you use the leftArrow.png image on the right button? I suspect that there is something wrong with the combination of the image alpha (if it has one) and the flexible space on the right

Comment: (to be more precise, it seems that the button takes the wrong width from the image, and so it's overlapped by the flexible space). But the image goes out the bound of the button, so for your eyes all seems correct

Comment: Now *that* is an interesting thought.  I will definitely test that out and let you know.